# Slurm Standalone system ubuntu 16.04.3 (compiled) not working: Authentication

Tags: linux, authentication, ubuntu-16.04, slurm

So I have been fighting with Installing slurm for a while now and am really at a loss. **My Goal is to install Slurm on a single machine and submit jobs to it from the same machine.(via sbatch or srun)**

Initially I attempted to install via `apt install slurm-llnl` but the version is too far behind to work with Ubuntu 16.04.3.

So the next step was to compile Slurm from source. Downloading and extracting the tarball I ran

`./configure --prefix=/etc/init.d/ --sysconfdir=/etc/slurm-llnl/
make
make install`

I then added the following /etc/ld.so.conf.d/SlurmLib.conf

```
/etc/init.d/lib
/etc/init.d/lib/slurm
```

I then created my cgroup.conf, slurm.conf, and slurmdb.conf.

[cgroup.conf]

```
CgroupAutomount=yes
ConstrainCores=no
ConstrainRAMSpace=no
```

[slurm.conf]

```
ControlMachine=arroyavelab15
AuthType=auth/none
CryptoType=crypto/munge
MpiDefault=none
ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
ReturnToService=1
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/slurm_dir/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/slurm_dir/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/slurm_dir/spool/slurmd/
SlurmUser=danielsauceda
SlurmdUser=danielsauceda
StateSaveLocation=/var/slurm_dir/spool
SwitchType=switch/none
TaskPlugin=task/none
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
MinJobAge=300
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=300
Waittime=0
FastSchedule=1
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/linear
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/none
AccountingStoreJobComment=YES
ClusterName=cluster
JobCompType=jobcomp/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=5
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/slurm_dir/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=3
NodeName=arroyavelab15 NodeAddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xx CPUs=1 CoresPerSocket=1 ThreadsPerCore=1 State=UNKNOWN RealMemory=8000
PartitionName=debug Nodes=arroyavelab15 Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

[slurmdb.conf]

```
# slurmDBD info                                                                           
DbdAddr=localhost
DbdHost=localhost
SlurmUser=danielsauceda
DebugLevel=4
PidFile=/var/run/slurmdbd.pid
#                                                                                         
# Database info                                                                           
StorageType=accounting_storage/mysql
StoragePass=slurm
StorageUser=slurm
```

Finally after etecuting

```
./slurmctld -D
./slurmd -D
./slurmdbd -Dv
```

They all appear to be running (in there own separate terminals)

However when exectuting

`srun -N3 --nodes=1 --ntasks-per-node=1 hostname`

I get the following

```
srun: error: Couldn't find the specified plugin name for auth/munge looking at all files
srun: error: cannot find auth plugin for auth/munge
srun: error: cannot create auth context for auth/munge
srun: error: Couldn't find the specified plugin name for auth/munge looking at all files
srun: error: cannot find auth plugin for auth/munge
srun: error: cannot create auth context for auth/munge
srun: error: Couldn't find the specified plugin name for auth/munge looking at all files
srun: error: cannot find auth plugin for auth/munge
srun: error: cannot create auth context for auth/munge
srun: error: authentication: authentication initialization failure
srun: error: Srun communication socket apparently being written to by something other than Slurm
srun: error: Unable to allocate resources: Protocol authentication error
```

I don't know what the problem is and online research has not been much help.

Comment: Looks like  `munge` was not detected on your system when you ran `configure`. Make sure to install munge first

Comment: so I have compiled and installed it but  ldconfig doesn't show up

Comment: according to your slurm.conf it should not be looking for auth/munge, so it seems that slurm is reading another slurm.conf file than the one you posted here.

Comment: It doesn't fail to run. Only commands like srun, sinfo, sbatch, etc fail to run

Comment: I don't think so. It does run. Only commands like srun, sinfo, sbatch etc fail.

Comment: @CarlesFenoy no, it does run. Only commands like srun, sinfo, sbatch fail.

Comment: Check in the slurmctld log which file it's using as config file

Answer (score 1):

Install munge from the package manager, and then build slurm --with-munge= option, auth_munge.so should appear under $PREFIX/lib/slurm